# itextsharp - Error in htmlWorker.Parse(string html) if img tag

Tags: c#, itext

When i am using `htmlWorker.Parse(html)` method it gives an error when there is `img` tag in the `html`.

For example :-

```
string html = "<p><img src=\"http://www.example.com/image001.jpg\" alt=\"\" /></p>"
```

> Cannot access a closed Stream

How to solve this error?

Comment: As explained in the [FAQ](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/parsing-xml-and-xhtml), `HTMLWorker` has been abandoned in favor of XML Worker. Bugs or problems with `HTMLWorker` will not be fixed.

Comment: I have found why this error occurs. When the image specified in the src does not exists on the web then there is error. Otherwise it is working perfectly.